# Liferay: Site logo

Tags: themes, liferay, graphical-logo

I have a Liferay portal and 2 different sites or companies. Each of them has its own theme and content, but the logo is the same for both sites.

I know I can remove the common logo and add a different logo in each theme, but what I want to know is if it's possible to change a logo for an only site from the control panel.

Comment: There's a big ambiguity in your question: You probably mean to have two sites. "Company", as a technical name, describes what Liferay's UI calls "instance" - as instances are completely independent of each other, here you could just change the "global logo" for each instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have separate logos for Public pages and Private pages of a given site, here is how you can do that:

[image]